# How would you count every occurrence of a term in all files in the current directory?

Tags: linux, search, file-management, grep, working-directory

How would you count every occurrence of a term in all files in the current directory? - and subdirectories(?)

I've read that to do this you would use `grep`; what is the exact command?

Also, is it possible to the above with some other command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, just pipe it to wc:

```
grep -Ro "searchTerm" . | wc -w
```

-R means recursive, -o means it will return only the matching words.
Then you pipe it into wc (wordcount) -w means it will count words.
Might be a bit trickier if the pattern you are searching for includes spaces, in which case they have to be escaped.

Note that the -w option will return the number of matches, so you have N matches on 1 line, it will return N, not 1.